# How to format date to 'yyyy-MM-dd' using Apex while making SOAP callout

Tags: apex, callout

I am making a SOAP callout from Apex for that I have to pass one date value as parameter in that callout.
When I try pass a value as `date.valueof(system.today())` time is also getting appended but as per the SOAP request that field is in `xsd:date` its accept date only in this format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I am confused how to achieve this. Looking your help if anyone have done this before.

```
serviceCheck.ShipDate = date.valueOf(system.today());
```

but the date coming as in this format `2020-05-11 00:00:00`. I have to remove the time value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the `date` using string methods

```
serviceCheck.ShipDate = String.valueOf(System.today()) //Result: 2020-05-11
```

Please note that the System.today will execute based on your timezone so it is best to send the timezone information as well or UTC offset or send the GMT date using

```
String.valueOf(System.now().dateGmt())
```

Comment: I generated the apex class from wsdl in that it created that field as date. Can I change the datatype as String and shall i try?

Comment: Yes, you can do that unless it has a lot of dependencies. It is useful to have a Date type if when you have an inbound soap service as Salesforce create a dat object from it.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to convert date into DateTime.

Then, if you want the date in the local time zone of the user, use below code

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(system.today().year(),system.today().month(), system.today().day(), 0 , 0,0);
String strDate = myDateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

If you want GMT

```
String strDate = myDateTime.formatGmt(dateFormatString);
```